# Python: Best way to keep track of particular values within dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I'm using SQLAlchemy to query a db.  The resulting output is a list of dictionaries.

Sample output

```
[{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q1', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q2', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q3', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '0', 'question': 'q4', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q5', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q1', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q2', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q3', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q4', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q5', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647}]
```

I need to keep track of the values for the corresponding questions.  ie

if there are two 'q5' columns I need to increment by the value.

Desired output:

```
[Charlie, q1, 2], [Charlie, q2, 2]
```

but because 1 of the q4's has a value of 0, it would be

```
[Charlie, q4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
# Results container
results = {}

# Collect the data
for item in data:
    # key here is just for later, 
    # you could use anything unique to the entry 
    # (username for example)
    key = "{0}.{1}".format(item.get('user_name'), item.get('question'))
    if key in results:
        results[key] += item.get('value', 0)
    else:
        results[key] = item.get('value', 0)

# Prints the results as you would like.
for key, count in results.iteritems():
   name, question = key.split('.')
   print [name, question, count]
```

Comment: Thanks for the above.  Will give this a shot and up-vote when successful.  Though it appears it may suit my needs, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Merge the results together.

```
def merge_dicts(results):
    out = {}
    for result in results:
        res = out.get(result["question"])
        if res is None:
            result["value"] = int(result["value"])
            res = result
        else:
            res["value"] += int(result["value"])
        out[res["question"]] = res
    return out.values()

a = merge_dict([{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q1', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q2', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q3', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '0', 'question': 'q4', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q5', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4054810},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q1', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q2', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q3', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q4', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647},
{'status': 'complete', 'value': '1', 'question': 'q5', 'user_name': u'Charlie', 'id': 4018647}])
```